# Failed to create lock file webview_data.lock

Tags: android, webview, chromium, yandex-metrika

We are facing an exception that I have no idea how to resolve to. It seems to be related to webviews and multi processing and our app does use up to 4 processes. However I would expect this crash on Android 9 because multiprocessing requires webviews to call `WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(suffix)` and we are already calling it. Frankly, Android 9 and 10 seems to be fine out of 70 crashes so far.

I would not expect this crash on other versions, though it happens on Android 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0 only. Application is proguarded but the mapping file is uploaded to Crashlytics so I expected a better stack trace but this is only I have. I don't know why this happens, I wasn't able to produce this locally with our Android 5 and 6 devices, or emulator. It only happens on production but frequently.

The application uses Firebase Analytics, Google Ads with various mediations and in app billing if that helps. And, we've recently added something called [Yandex Metrica](https://appmetrica.yandex.com/docs/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/android-initialize.html) which runs in its own process with the suffix ":Metrica". My guess is that it comes from there because the code in Metrica uses the component "java.nio.FileLock" and tries to acquire a lock. At least, that's what I've found by decompiling our APK and searching for that package.

### Edit

This may be wrong because apparently another app of ours throw the same exception without using Yandex Metrica.

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create lock file /data/user/0/com.example.app/app_webview/webview_data.lock
       at org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.a + 22(AwDataDirLock.java:22)
       at F8.g + 46(F8.java:46)
       at E8.run + 2(E8.java:2)
       at Kw.f + 11(Kw.java:11)
       at Jw.run(Jw.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 743(Handler.java:743)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 95(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 171(Looper.java:171)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5417(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 726(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 616(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.aar')
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.anrwatchdog:anrwatchdog:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1"
implementation('com.labo.kaji:swipeawaydialog:0.1.1') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
implementation 'com.github.zurche:plain-pie:v0.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.1'

// Yandex API Metrica implementation.
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.10.0'

// Ads

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:9.8.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.6.0.0'
implementation 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:2.1.0'
implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.7.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude module: 'libAvid-mopub' // To exclude AVID
    exclude module: 'moat-mobile-app-kit' // To exclude Moat
}
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:mopub:5.7.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:7.3.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:tapjoy:12.3.1.0'
implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.1.0.0'

// Crashlytics implementation.
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
implementation ("com.kochava.base:tracker:3.5.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.1"

// Required: Install Referrer (If publishing to Google Play)
// noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1'

// Required: To track down latest updates
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'

// Required: To track down notifications.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:17.0.0'

// Optional: Instant App Status Collection
implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'

// Required for Flurry Analytics integration
implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.4.0@aar'

// Crashlytics implementation.
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

// Multidex implementation.
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'

// Don't update these libraries. They cause below API 21 to crash.
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'
implementation 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul did you find anything useful? I'm facing similar crashes which happen sometimes. Though, I'm not using Yandex Metrica.

Comment: Not really, it still happens I'm afraid.